# String C++, strlen

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char s[100] = "(())())";
    int p = 0;
    for(int i(0);i < strlen(s);i++){
        if (s[i] == "("){parni++;}
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Почему не работает, подскажите пожалуйста.

> test.cpp|9|error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and
>   integer [-fpermissive]|

Comment: Что означает «не работает»? Какого эффекта вы ожидаете? Ваша программа ничего не выводит.

Comment: @VladD, суть не в том, суть в том, что выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: Да, вы сравниваете символ со строкой, это не правильно. Скорее всего, вы имели в виду `s[i] == '('`.

Comment: Ну, ошибку лучше писать в вопросе, чтобы нам не угадывать.

Comment: @VladD, действительно, огромное спасибо!:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Какая дикая мешанина из C и C++... Для начала, оно не "не работает", а **не компилируется**:

1. Переменная `parni` нигде не объявлена.
2. Сравнение `s[i] == "("` некорректно (скорее всего, имелось в виду сравнение с символом `'('`).

Впрочем, обо всём этом в явном виде говорит компилятор. Если ваш этого не сказал - выкиньте его на помойку и найдите нормальный.

```
1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
1.cpp:9:21: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
         if (s[i] == "("){parni++;}
                     ^
1.cpp:9:26: error: ‘parni’ was not declared in this scope
         if (s[i] == "("){parni++;}
                          ^
```

Comment: Да "parni' это техническая ошибка при вводе в Вопрос:) А вот за символ, спасибо!

Comment: @goodalien1125, просто не нужно пугаться ошибок. Они были, есть и будут у любого программиста, всегда. А нужно - внимательно читать что там пишут. Даже если на иноземном, язык-то совсем простой, понять можно. В крайнем случае скопировать и вбить в яндекс. Раз уж это ошибка, которую выдаёт компилятор - уверяю, любая из них уже встречалась у миллионов программистов, миллион раз обсуждена, разжёвана, и даже на русском :)